Was that a Coordinatorlayout Setting error or script error?
I want to set a new project with a very simple "FAB" button, but I get an error message at the end. Here is my laout activity_main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:rippleColor="#ff0000ff"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffff0000"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="10dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linLay"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

And here is my MainActivity.xml
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton mFab;
    private TextView mTxtMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTxtMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
        mFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        mFab.setOnClickListener(mFabOnClick);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mFabOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mTxtMsg.setText("You press a FAB button！");
        }
    };
}

I googled the problem and add the following amendment to the build.gradle.kts:
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation ("androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0") // This is the new line I add.
}


And for the setting.gradle.kts, both google() and mavencentral() had been added(by android studio, not me) to repositories() already in the setting.gradle.kts.
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Test"
include(":app")

But after I genearate the apk, it still crashes. 
My Android studio version is 2024.1.2 Patch2.
What is the problem? How shall I correct it?
What is the problem? How shall I correct it?

You have declared Coordinator Layout in XML and casting it to FAB in Java, that's what the error says. To fix it, in XMl, change Coordinator Layout to Material library's Floating Action Button.
